# Проблема с очисткой куки

Tags: c#

Суть проблемы: в приложении используется контрол Windows.Forms.WebBrowser. Если запускать форму с данным контролом и чистить куки на жестком диске, то все равно данные куки подгружаются, хотя их физически нет. Пробывал загружать через AppDomain - та же история. Только после перезагрузки приложения все работает как надо. Вопрос в том как очистить куки и запустить данный контрол без перезагрузки приложения?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для очистки всех данных сессии попробуйте вызывать функцию Windows API `InternetSetOption` c параметром `INTERNET_OPTION_END_BROWSER_SESSION`:

```
InternetSetOption(IntPtr.Zero, INTERNET_OPTION_END_BROWSER_SESSION, IntPtr.Zero, 0);
```

где:

```
private const int INTERNET_OPTION_END_BROWSER_SESSION = 42;

[DllImport("wininet.dll", SetLastError = true)]
private static extern bool InternetSetOption(IntPtr internet, int option, IntPtr buffer, int length);
```